# Non maximal prime ideals and localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, localization

In the chapter on localization in Neukirch, *Algebraic Number Theory*, the following is mentioned:

> (A is an integral domain) Usually $S$ will be the complement of a union $\bigcup_{\mathfrak p \in X}\mathfrak p$ over a set $X$ of prime ideals of $A$. In this case one writes $$A(X) = \{\frac fg \mid f,g \in A, g \not \equiv 0 \bmod{\mathfrak p}\text{ for }\mathfrak p\in X\}$$
>   The prime ideals of $A(X)$ correspond $1-1$ to the prime ideals of $A$ which are contained in $\bigcup_{\mathfrak p \in X}\mathfrak p$. For instance if $X$ is finite or omits only finitely many prime ideals of $A$, then only the prime ideals from $X$ survive in $A(X)$.

The passage seems to say that the only prime ideals contained in $\bigcup_{\mathfrak p \in X}\mathfrak p$ are those in $X$ but is this true in general? What if there is some prime ideal contained in one of the ideals of $X$?

Comment: Sorry: but your question is not clear. Take simply $\mathfrak{p} \in x$ and suppose that it is not maximal.

Comment: The passage seems to say that the only prime ideals contained in $\bigcup_{\mathfrak p \in x}\mathfrak p$ are those in $x$ but is this true in general? What if there is some prime ideal contained in one of the ideals of $x$. Does this clarify the question?

Comment: OK, now I understand the question. Yes: the book says something not so clear. For example, in the case that you have some chain of primes $\mathfrak{p}_1 \subset \mathfrak{p}_2 \subset \mathfrak{p}_3$, and $x=\{ \mathfrak{p}_3 \}$, you have that $\mathfrak{p}_1 , \mathfrak{p}_2$ survive as well.